# Find the limits, if exists

Tags: calculus

My question here is about limits. Find the following limit if it exists. If the limit does not exist, distinguish between a limit that goes (+) infinity or (-) inifinity and DNE.  NO graphing calculators!  [image: Find the limit]

Comment: If you have an answer, why are you asking here?

Comment: I want to know if it is the same as what you guys would say. I'm fairly new to this stuff and I want to get the concept down.

Comment: [l'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x^{53}-1=(x-1)(x^{52}+x^{51}+\cdots+x+1)$ and $x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+\cdots+x+1)$.

Cancel the $x-1$'s. Now you can safely let $x\to 1$.

The only risk now is miscounting: note that $x^6+x^5+\cdots +x+1$ has $7$ terms.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Someone did not like it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So what happens next after, I'm still stuck. :/

Comment: It is finished. The limit as $x$ approaches $1$ of $x^{52}+x^{51}+\cdots+x+1$ is $53$, the limit of $x^6+\cdots+1$ is $7$, so our limit is $\frac{53}{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

We see that the function is of the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ when we attempt to take the limit. Therefore:
Using L'Hopitals rule $$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}}{\frac{d}{dx}} \frac{x^{53}-1}{x^7-1} = \frac{53x^{52}}{7x^6}$$ which if we take $\lim_{x\to1}$ we obtain simply $\frac{53}{7}$

Comment: I haven't learned L'hopitals rule, is there a different way to approach this question? Couldn't I just plug 1 into the x to find the limit?

Comment: If you plug in $1$ you output $\frac{0}{0}$ which does not give us the proper answer, do you agree?

Comment: yes so therefore the limit does not exist? or is the answer simply 0?

Comment: @jayson The limit does indeed exist. Refer to Andre's solution below as well. We see that $x^{53} -1 = (x-1)(\sum_{n=0}^{52} x^n$ which, after canceling yields 53. Similarly, in the denominator, it will yield 7.

Comment: oh i see i see, your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @jayson that's why we're here, be sure to mark an answer as your accepted answer too

Comment: yeah i know, it's making me wait

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Your notation is a bit off. The $d/dx$ should stand on numerator and denominator separately.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}=1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1}$$

Use this top and bottom.